# How get Azure KeyVault secret for C# IIS application running on premise

Tags: azure-keyvault

Is there any way to get a key vault secret using the IIS app pool identity to authenticate?

The typical solution for reading values from Azure KeyVault is

```
AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
result = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(secretUrl).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

While this work under visual studio, and even for a Windows/console application, it doesn't work for an IIS application - even when the app pool is configured with an identity that would otherwise work.

All the solutions I've found to date require a service principle and supplying its id and secret which - and it's storing secrets locally that I'm trying to avoid.

Example: https://blog.bitscry.com/2019/02/13/using-azure-key-vault-in-a-console-application/

```
var keyClient = new KeyVaultClient(async (authority, resource, scope) => {
    var adCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, null);
    return (await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, adCredential)).AccessToken;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to get a key vault secret using the IIS app pool identity to authenticate?

For [local development authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#local-development-authentication), `AzureServiceTokenProvider` fetches tokens using **Visual Studio**, **Azure command-line interface (CLI)**, or **Azure AD Integrated Authentication**.

Using Visual Studio and Azure CLI both need to sign in to azure. And the User should be add to `Access Policy` of Azure keyvault.

Using Azure ad Integrated authentication, you also need to add the `service principal` into the `Access Policy` .

However, if you want to use IIS app pool identity to authenticate, you could not add [Application Pool Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) Accounts to Azure keyvault. So, you could not avoid to use service principal's id and secret to authenticate.

Comment: you can also try the clientid / certificate approach. As it would be more secure to install te cert on the iis serve (in the user cert) then your app can call key vault by providing the cert.

Comment: And this is true even when the AppPool Identity has be updated to a service account that has access to the KeyVault?

Comment: Maybe you could add the service principal's id and secret in the credential manager that is built into Windows. That way, you avoid a chicken-and-the-egg situation.